# Как в input с правой стороны расположить текст дополнительный?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как в input с правой стороны расположить текст дополнительный заместо картинки?

```css
.banner_input {
  background: #fff url("http://icofx.ro/tutorials2/img/top.png") 220px 15px no-repeat;
  margin: 0 50px 0 5px;
  padding: 16px 45px;
}
```

```html
<input class="banner_input" type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saneq11/4xc5nm6h/2/)

Answer (score 4):

В инпут никак, но можно сделать поверх инпута. Как вариант вот так:

```css
.input-wrp {
position: relative;
}

.input-wrp__txt {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 10px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.banner_input {
  padding: 16px 45px;
}
```

```html
<label class="input-wrp">
  <input class="banner_input" type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
  <div class="input-wrp__txt">Тут наш текст</div>
</label>
```

Comment: Не забывайте про то. что клик по тексту, должен фокусировать на `input`.

Comment: Поэтому текст и инпут находятся внутри label